# Marshal.QueryInterface() - How to use the returned value?

Tags: c#, com

I was trying to find an answer to this, but with no luck at all. There is no documentation on how to use the value returned by the `Marshal.QueryInterface` (in my case 'pISomething'). It is an instance of `IntPtr`, but I need it as instance of `ISomething`. Simple cast is not working. So, can somebody show how to use an interface returned by the `Marshal.QueryInterface`?

example:

```
IBaseFilter pMyFilter = getMyFilter();

IntPtr pUnknown = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(pMyFilter);

IntPtr pISomething;
int success = Marshal.QueryInterface(pUnknown, ref IID_ISomething, out pISomething);

// success = 0 here!
```

Comment: `success` value is a `HRESULT`, not a `bool`. That means that 0 is actually `S_OK`, which means it succeeded. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx

Comment: @Zdeslav, thanks for the COM basics, but that was not the question. I have a `pISomething` now and there is nothing I can do with it. How to call some method on that COM object, that's my problem?

Comment: Oh right, I understood that it was failing. What error do you get on cast? I would expect it to work?

Comment: What exception do you get on cast? what do you get when you call `Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown` on `pISomething`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a low-level method, like about all of the Marshal methods, not intended to do what you want.  You only use it if you need to pass an interface pointer to native code.

The CLR will automatically call IUnknown::QueryInterface() for you, without having to program it explicitly.  You do so by simply using a cast in your C# code:

```
 ISomething itf = (ISomething)pMyFilter;
```

Do note that this will throw an exception if the object doesn't implement the interface.  Do note that ISomething must have been declared with the [ComImport] attribute, just like IBaseFilter was.  Automatic if you imported a type library.  It is that attribute that provides the IID that the CLR needs to properly call QueryInterface.

Comment: How do you explain that `ISomething itf = (ISomething)pMyFilter;` fails, while `int success = Marshal.QueryInterface(pUnknown, ref IID_ISomething, out pISomething);` succeeds?

Comment: There's no point in forcing me to guess what "fails" means.  There's at least a decent compile or exception message.