# C# - Marshal.QueryInterface() - How To Use?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, com, queryinterface

I'm playing around with C# and COM, and I'm doing pretty well at understanding how to convert C++ COM into C# declarations and code for usage.

I have, however, become stuck on `Marshal.QueryInterface()`.

I know I can directly 'cast' from one `IUnknown`-derived type to a higher one, which implicitly does the `QueryInterface()` - which is neat. But for my learning, could someone tell me how I use `Marshal.QueryInterface()`, please? I'm struggling with interfaces versus `IntPtrs`.

The declaration is

```
Marshal.QueryInterface(IntPtr pUnk, ref Guid iid, out IntPtr ppv)
```

- `pUnk` needs needs to come from an existing defined interface; the compiler seems happy with `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(my_ISomething)` (am I heading for a world of pain here?).
- The GUID is easy - I have an example from elsewhere.
- `ppv` I declare as `IntPtr`... but how do I get the `ISomething2` interface back out of it?

There's [this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969155/marshal-queryinterface-how-to-use-the-returned-value), but the answer was 'don't'. I'm trying to *learn* here - I will be using the simple 'cast' in the real thing.

Thanks.

Comment: As the linked answer mentioned, the returned pointer points to an unmanaged interface. In the managed world, com interfaces are wrapped in managed wrappers, so you cannot get the interface back.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. I guess they have some internal use for it - I wish they'd hide it from us if it's not meant to be used...

Comment: In .NET COM objects can be represented as objects (RCW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/runtime-callable-wrapper) or just by their native pointer (32 or 64bit depending on process bitness), that's as simple as that. Modern .NET code (core, C#/Winrt, etc.) tend to use pointers more than objects. You can use various Marshal methods to convert from one representation to the other (it's not meant really for .NET COM objects which are represented by their CCW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/com-callable-wrapper).